# JQTouch causing issues on Android

Tags: jquery, iphone, android, jqtouch

As per my title I'm having JQTouch issues on Android. I have several drop down menus that are completely unresponsive on the device. They open on iphone and any desktop browser I've tried. The one thing that might be worth noting is that I've added a background image to the dropdowns to fit my theme.

Is this something that's come up for anyone, I haven't been able to find any documentation on this at all.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently experiencing such things when form fields within a scrollable (s-scrollwrapper etc.) div. Haven't found a solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you want to try something official
http://jquerymobile.com/